# I have a list with 13 numbers and i want to multiply them together

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string `numbers` which contains `13` digits, e.g.:

```
string numbers = "01234567890123456781";
```

and I have to **multiply** them:

```
0 * 1 * 2 * 3 * ... * 7 * 8 * 1
```

I've a got a solution for **adding** the digits together:

```
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 7 + 8 + 1
```

I convert `number` string to `List<int> numb` and then sum items of the list with a help of *Linq* `Sum()` method:

```
        string numbers = "01234567890123456781";
        List<int> numb = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            int num = int.Parse(numbers[i].ToString());
            numb.Add(num);
        }

        for (int b = 0; b <numb.Count()-12; b++)
        {
            var x = numb.Skip(b).Take(13);
            int a = x.Sum(); // <- it's easy to sum, but what shall I do to multiply?
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
```

However, *Linq* doesn't have any `Mult()` or alike method, so what can I do to *multiply* the items together?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please see our guidelines on asking questions and how to phrase a question correctly (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, I believe your question has been answered nevertheless.

Comment: @Sam: I've edited your question; next time, please, try to be as clear as you can when describing the expected outcome, your efforts, and the exact problem (Linq does have `Sum()`, but no trace of `.Mult()` in your case)

Answer (score 3):

Providing that the `numbers` contains digits `[0..9]` only, a simple *Linq* will do:

```
  // since 0 * anything == 0, I've removed all 0's to obtain non-zero result:
  // 1 * 2 * 3 * ... * 7 * 8 * 1 
  string numbers = "123456789123456781";

  // long: int is not large enough
  long result = numbers
    .Select(c => (long) (c - '0'))
    .Aggregate((s, a) => s * a);
```

Outcome:

```
  // 14631321600
  Console.Write(result);
```

`Aggregate` (custom aggregation) will do if you want to change `IEnumerable<T>.Sum()` from summation (as in your current code) to multiplication:

```
  ...
  var x = numb.Skip(b).Take(13); //TODO: get rid of magic number 13
  // instead of summation
  // int a = x.Sum();
  // let's use multiplication as a custom aggregation:
  // please, mind overflow: int is not enough when multiplying items
  long a = x
    .Select(item => (long) item) 
    .Aggregate((s, item) => s * item);
```